# If an exponential function takes the form $ab^x$ then how is is e.g. $0.875^x$ an exponential function (there's no b)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've just started reading a chapter on exponential functions [here](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/6-1-exponential-functions). In this chapter, the book reads:

> For any real number x, an exponential function is a function with the form
> $f(x)=ab^x$

I am confused about the $a$ and $b$ parts.

The book says:
[image]

Then, right underneath it we have:
[image]

If a must be a non zero real number and b is any positive real number such that b <> 1, then that doesn't fit with the answers in example 1 screen shot above. For example, in that screen shot we have $h(x)=(\frac{1}{3})^x$ is an exponential function.

If that is true what is a and what is b? Presumably the fraction $\frac{1}{3}$ is the 'initial value' part. Then what is b?

> b is any positive real number such that b does not equal 1

Comment: $a=1, b=0.875$? Initial value is the value of the function when $x=0$.

Comment: $f(x)=0.875^x=1\cdot 0.875^x$ is of the desired form.  Recall that you can always multiply by $1$ and add zero without changing the value of something.  $a$ being equal to $1$ is not a problem.  $b$ was required not to be equal to $1$ just since $1^x=1$ for all $x$ and so the curve would have been flat.  We prefer to call such a function with $b=1$ a "*constant function*" rather than an exponential one (*though one could argue that it is also an exponential function, just a "degenerate case"*)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that similar arithmetic/algebraic modifications and rearrangements can be performed on the others.  For example, $4^{3(x-2)}=4^{-6}\cdot 4^{3x}=\frac{1}{4096}\cdot 64^x$ is also an exponential function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{1}{3}$ is being raised to the power $x$, it is $\frac{1}{3}$ that is equal to $b$. In the case of $h(x) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^x$, since there is no coefficient in front of $\left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^x$ your initial value $a$ will be equal to $1$ (because $1b^x$ is just $b^x$).